# Converting Raster to Point Shapefile

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, points

I am trying to convert raster to point shapefiles

```
> library (raster)
> ras <- raster("dem.tif")
> pts = rasterToPoints(ras)
> pts
               x         y       Z
   [1,] 70.87500 38.375007  5.035302e+14
   [2,] 71.12500 38.375007  4.563356e+14
   [3,] 70.62500 38.125007  4.987732e+14
   [4,] 70.87500 38.125007  4.108542e+14
   [5,] 71.12500 38.125007  4.114788e+14
   [6,] 70.37500 37.875006  6.538783e+14
   [7,] 70.62500 37.875006  5.798219e+14
   [8,] 70.87500 37.875006  5.045395e+14
   [9,] 71.12500 37.875006  4.315951e+14
> writeOGR(p, ".", "output_name, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
Error in writeOGR(p, ".", "filename", driver = "ESRI Shapefile") : 
  inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE
> raster::shapefile(pts, "output_name.shp")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shapefile’ for signature ‘"matrix"’
> shapefile(p, outfile, overwrite=TRUE)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shapefile’ for signature ‘"matrix"’
>plot(pts)
```

[image]
Where am i wrong in converting these files into shapefile?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `pts = rasterToPoints(ras, spatial = TRUE)` to ensure that `pts` is a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. As is, it is just a `matrix` (as stated in the error message), so can't be exported as a shapefile.

Comment: All write code works now..thanks to you @caldwelist  ..can you suggest how to convert raster to point shapefile for nlayers? i tried ```pts = rasterToPoints(ras_stck, spatial = TRUE, bylayer=TRUE)``` but it's giving error msg:  Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for signature ‘"character"’

Comment: `bylayer` doesn't seem to be an accepted argument for `rasterToPoints`, so you will likely need to find another package that deals with vector data, and create versions of `pts` for each attribute (assuming `rasterToPoints` creates a points file with an attribute for each layer).